# tab bar controllers won't open in Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, view, uitabbarcontroller

I'm developing a new app but I've a little issue with Interface Builder...
I've installed Xcode 3.2.3 and iPhone SDK 4.0 GM.
When I create a new Tab Bar Application project in Xcode, opening the MainWindow.xib file in IB, the Tab Bar Controller won't open... I tried reclicking it but nothing!
I also uninstalled and reinstalled all developer tools but without any results...
Finally if I try to build and run the project in the simulator, the tab bar controller shows normally!

Can anyone help me? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like something similar to what I have experienced with my projects and the new sdk. Some of my IB files such as ones that contain UIViews when double clicking on them they refuse to open.

I haven't had to reinstall or nothing usually quitting IB and xcode and restarting helps I can't remember if I have done anything else to fix it. It may be an issue with the new 3.2.3 xcode as I don't recall having anything like this happen in my 3.2.2 build.

If it becomes a large problem for you have you considered removing the tab bar and rebuilding it? Just a thought. It may be troublesome to do so but if it fixes it and allows you to continue coding your project it would be worth it.

Comment: Oh thanks, I've just resolved this problem rebuilding tab bar controller :)

Answer (score 0):

You said in your question that you're running iPhone SDK 3.2.3 with iOS4 **GM**. You should update your SDK, as the SDK is now at version 4.0 officially.

Otherwise, it sounds like your Xcode installation is somehow corrupted in some way. You may need a complete reinstall.